# join between two tables without(foreign_key&primary collection giving duplicate rows)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have 3 tables with their column:-

**Chapter**:-Id(primary key)
                        Name
**Question Bank**:-Id(primary key),
           
     Name,
               
Chapter_id(as foreign key),
                 Question_list(applied as JSON data type,contains array of chapter id)
**Question**:-Id(primary key)
                name,
                chapter_id (as foreign key refernces chapter's id)

Question to chapter relation:-One to one(means one question can be added in one chapter,it can not be added in more than one chapter)

Question Bank to chapter:-Many to one(Means per chapter we can create no of question banks)

As one question can belong to no. of question_banks.So I added Column as  Question_list  (in Question Bank Table) which consist of list of id of questions as **json** datatype.

So let me know is this design correct??

please tell me query to get desired result as below

Suppose following are my tables

**Chapter**
------------------------------------------------------
Id      Name
-------------------------------------------------------
1     general
------------------------------------------------------
2     Technical
**Question**
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id              Name                              Chapter_id
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     what is name of my pet              1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2     what is name of my car              1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3     what is name of my friend              1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4     what is capital of india              1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5     what are oops concept in java              2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6     how to compile java              2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7     what is array in php              2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Question_bank**
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id              Name                  Question list       Chapter_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Question_bank1          1,2                       1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2       Question_bank2          1,3,4                       1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       Question_bank3          5,6                       2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4       Question_bank4          7                       2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5       Question_bank5          6,7                       2
Suppose i want to get all question whhich belongs to **Technical** chapter with their respective questionbank id,then result should be display as below
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
chapter_id         question_bank        question_id        question_name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         question_bank_3                      5               what are oops concept in java
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         question_bank_3                      6               how to compile java
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         question_bank_4                      7               what is array in php
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         question_bank_5                      6               how to compile java
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2         question_bank_5                      7               what is array in php
same as for if i select chapter as **General**.If I select both technical & general chapter query should return question from question_bank belongs to respective chapter.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Please add the SQL query that you've already tried with corresponding result. It's quite possible that it can be slightly adjusted to get you to the desired result.

Comment: select qb.chapter_id,qb.name as question_bank,qb.id as questionbank_id,q.name as question_name  
from questions as q
inner join 
(select chapter_id,question_bank.id,name ,question_list from  question_bank  where id in (4,5) ) as qb
on  qb.chapter_id=q.chapter_id
where qb.chapter_id =5

Comment: where <b>5</b> in where clause is selected chapter_id

Comment: where 5 in where clause is selected chapter_id

Comment: and (4,5)in where clause of sub query is list of id's of question bank which belong to selected chapter.I have written 2 queries one to fetch list of questionbank_list belongs to selected chapter.And second to fetch question dependent of id(of question bank) i have got from first query

Comment: It would be much better if you add full version of the request it to your question, formatted as a code, as well as result which you've got.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should save a question list as a single row in question_bank instead comma separated, find the query below to fetch the data as per your diagram. let us know if you face issue in the query that you have used or in the below. :) Happy coding.

```
select q.name as question_name, q.id as question_id, qb.name as question_bank, c.id as chapter_id 
from chapter as c
join question as q on q.chapter_id = c.id
join question_bank as qb on qb.chapter_id = q.chapter_id
where c.id = 2;
```

Comment: one its giving duplicate result&as well as i want result as questions from question bank which contains list of questions

Comment: means firstly it will search question bank belongs to selected chapter.After that it wil fetch out question information retrived question bank's question list.Your above query  retrieving that question also qhich does not belong to any question bank,but it have chapter_id same as selected chapter id